# Problem with PLPGSQL function return, uuid involved

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to assign serial numbers from a sequence, along with uuids that are generated automatically. My table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE master_serialnumbers
(
    uuident     uuid            PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(),
    serno       integer         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    requester   varchar(20)     NOT NULL
);
```

I can now generate a serial number with

```
INSERT INTO master_serialnumbers(requester) VALUES ('XY') 
RETURNING (uuident,serno,requester);
```

To automate this and generate a block of several serial numbers, I can use a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gen_serials_A(num_serials integer, req varchar(20)) 
RETURNS SETOF master_serialnumbers
AS $$
DECLARE
    new_id uuid;
    rr master_serialnumbers%ROWTYPE;        -- or simply RECORD
    tmpSQL TEXT;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'generate % serial numbers', num_serials;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpIds (id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
    
    FOR i IN 1..num_serials LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'serno %', i;
        INSERT INTO master_serialnumbers(space, requester) VALUES (spc, req) 
            RETURNING (uuident) INTO new_id;
        INSERT INTO tmpIds(id) VALUES (new_id);
    END LOOP;

    FOR rr IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM master_serialnumbers 
                       WHERE uuident IN (SELECT id FROM tmpIds)' LOOP
        RETURN NEXT rr;
    END LOOP;

    tmpSQL := 'DROP TABLE tmpIds';
    EXECUTE tmpSQL;

RETURN;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This does work, but it seems cumbersome to store the values in a temporary table and have two loops. So I tried to shorten it like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gen_serials(num_serials integer, req varchar(20)) 
RETURNS SETOF master_serialnumbers
AS $$
DECLARE
    rr master_serialnumbers%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'generate % serial numbers', num_serials;
    
    FOR i IN 1..num_serials LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'serno %', i;
        INSERT INTO master_serialnumbers(requester) VALUES (req)
            RETURNING (uuident,serno,requester) INTO rr;
        RAISE NOTICE 'rr is %', rr;
        RETURN NEXT rr;
    END LOOP;

RETURN;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

– but the `INSERT` throws an error

```
invalid input syntax for type uuid: »(12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc,1,A)«
```

Changing the declaration to `rr RECORD` now passes the `INSERT`:

```
rr is ("(12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc,1,A)")
ERROR:  wrong record type supplied in RETURN NEXT
DETAIL:  Returned type does not match expected type uuid in column 1.
```

Apparently all has been converted into a string.

And changing the return type also to `SETOF RECORD` yields another error:

```
ERROR: function with set result called in a context that cannot process set results
```

*(German error messages translated back to English by me, sorry for that).*

Any ideas what's (not) happening here? Perhaps I am doing it much too long-winded at all by using a function with procedural loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To automate this and generate a block of several serial numbers, I can use a function

Don't make it so complicated. Use something like

```
INSERT INTO master_serialnumbers(requester)
VALUES ('XY', 'YZ', 'ZA') 
RETURNING uuident, serno, requester;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO master_serialnumbers(requester)
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['XY', 'YZ', 'ZA']) -- useful for parameterised queries
RETURNING uuident, serno, requester;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO master_serialnumbers(requester)
SELECT 'XY'
FROM generate_series(1, 20) -- useful for arbitrary repetition of the same value
RETURNING uuident, serno, requester;
```

(a [set-returning function to create a series of numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html))

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution, especially the third statement is exactly what I meant with my last question as it eliminates the need for a procedural loop. Thank you.

Do you have a quick hint how I can process the returned 3-tuples in an outer query? The `INSERT` only returns one composite column named `row`, not three.

Comment: Ok, that was easy: Just leave out the parantheses in the `RETURNING` clause.

Comment: Ah, indeed, that was also the problem you had in your function, returning a row with a single 3-tuple column instead of a row with 3 columns. I was confused where that happened, thanks for the resolution :-)